# Yii:app()->user->name ----- Why is it not working?

Tags: php, yii

I have written it in `layouts/main.php` but whenever I am trying to run the application following error has been occured

> Undefined property: CWebApplication::$user in ........ main.php on
>   line...

And how its work can anyone please explain.

```
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
```

Comment: Please someone help me....!!

Answer (score 0):

try using  `::` instead of `:`

```
   Yii::app()->user->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing static methods of a class php uses

```
classname::methodname();
```

so, to access the static app() methods of class Yii {}

```
class YiiBase {
  public static function app() {
    return self::$_app;
  }
}
class Yii extends YiiBase {
}
Yii::app(); //You, need to do this
```

[hope, this might help](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)